# MS access "Invalid use of Null"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working one MS access with ASV. I want to create a new job number and start a new evaluation. I created the job number successful, but when I Click the button "Select Job" to analysis all the sections it showed "Invalid use of Null".

I am not sure if you guys know the Baseline version of it. I post the code as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdSelectJob_Click()
 On Error GoTo Err_cmdSelectJob_Click
```

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code.  access-vba maybe?  VB6?

Comment: @Plutonix yes, thank you, I already changed it.

Comment: I suggest putting diagnostics closer to each line in your code. I notice you have a single "on error goto" at the top of your subroutine so you really have no idea where the failure is happening. Comment out your "on error goto" and see where it fails.

Comment: @n8wrl thank you very much, I try to debug it. If there is anything new, I will @ you.

Comment: @n8wrl Hi I comment the line of "on error goto" and got the error with "Run time error '94' Invalid use of Null".

Comment: It has been a very long time since I worked in Access, but the goal is the same - you have to identify which line is raising the error. Can you single-step it? Can you add some popup-type messages before each line so you know how far you got before it failed? You cannot just debug a whole block of code with a single error message.

Comment: so if the error is with the isNull, why dont you try reversiing the logic.
such as `if isnull(job number) or jobnumber = "" then
   exit
else run your code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem. Because of the code "If (RS!ForReview)" which is in the function UpdateBaseline and the "ForReview" column is null. I Changed the code to "If (RS.ForReview = NULL) ". This is working good. Thank you for any help.